# Running procdump and logging off the server

Tags: iis

We are getting some errors in IIS and we need to use procdump to capture the memory dump at the time of the crash.  But I found that when the user logs out of the system the procdump also stops monitoring for crash events.  Is there another tool or method within procdump that can be used to capture a memory dump of an IIS crash when there is no one logged on to the server?  Our production servers auto log the user out after X minutes of no-activity and we cannot change this security policy.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try running procdump from a remote system using [PsExec](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb897553).

```
psexec \\remote -u admin c:\path\to\procdump /accepteula procnametodump.exe c:\path\to\dumptocreate.dmp
```

Answer (score 0):

Can you create a local user, or is that blocked by your security policies too? If you can create a local user you could have that user run procdump as a scheduled task.

Answer (score 0):

If it's IIS 6.x, you could try DebugDiag.